# не работает z-index для дочерних элементов

Tags: html, css, position, z-index

```css
    .healthcare-card {
      padding: 37px 0;
      box-shadow: 0px 4px 18px rgba(88, 126, 236, 0.18);
      border-radius: 8px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 10;
    } 
    .healthcare__column {
      flex: 0 1 33.333%;
      padding: 36px;
      position: relative;
    }
    .healthcare__decore {
      position: absolute;
      width: 65.75px;
      height: 65.75px;
      border-radius: 16px;
      transform: rotate(-30deg);
    }
    .healthcare__decore_11 {
      bottom: 33px;
      left: 0;
    }
    .healthcare__decore_12 {
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="healthcare__column">
         <div class="healthcare__item healthcare-card">
              <div class="healthcare-card__icon">
                    <img src="/img/human.svg" alt="human">
               </div>
               <h4 class="healthcare-card__title">Symptom Checker</h4>
               <h5 class="healthcare-card__subtitle">Text</h5>
          </div>
         <div class="healthcare__decore healthcare__decore_11"></div>
         <div class="healthcare__decore healthcare__decore_12"></div>
    </div>
```

Элемент с классом healthcare-card должен перекрывать элементы с классом healthcare__decore. Элементы находятся на одном уровне, родитель общий healthcare__column. Позиционирование задано. Указал z-index для healthcare-card, но он не работает. В чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте фон элементу с классом `healthcare-card`, и все заработает. Поскольку у него нет фона, декоративные блоки просто "видно" за блоком `healthcare-card`(в примере добавил фон и декоративным блокам для наглядности)

```css
    .healthcare-card {
      padding: 37px 0;
      box-shadow: 0px 4px 18px rgba(88, 126, 236, 0.18);
      border-radius: 8px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 10;
      background: #fff;
    } 
    .healthcare__column {
      flex: 0 1 33.333%;
      padding: 36px;
      position: relative;
    }
    .healthcare__decore {
      position: absolute;
      width: 65.75px;
      height: 65.75px;
      border-radius: 16px;
      transform: rotate(-30deg);
      background: #000;
    }
    .healthcare__decore_11 {
      bottom: 33px;
      left: 0;
    }
    .healthcare__decore_12 {
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="healthcare__column">
         <div class="healthcare__item healthcare-card">
              <div class="healthcare-card__icon">
                    <img src="/img/human.svg" alt="human">
               </div>
               <h4 class="healthcare-card__title">Symptom Checker</h4>
               <h5 class="healthcare-card__subtitle">Text</h5>
          </div>
         <div class="healthcare__decore healthcare__decore_11"></div>
         <div class="healthcare__decore healthcare__decore_12"></div>
    </div>
```